# If inside fat arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, jsx, higher-order-functions

Im not sure how to write this. I have this ternary operator inside the fat arrow. but if fails to execute the code. I get no errors with browserify or on console, but it just does not print the headers.

If I drop the `{}` and ternary operator it works fine.

What am I typing wrong?

```
<Row className="grid-header">
    {
        this.props.columnsInfo.map((info) => {
            width = (info.colWidth) ? "className={info.colWidth}" : "xs={this.calculateColumnSize()}";
            <Col style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }} key={info.header} width>{info.header}</Col>
        })
    }
</Row>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly return the jsx if it's not the entire body of the fat arrow function.

Your code fixed:

```
<Row className="grid-header">
    {this.props.columnsInfo.map(info => {
            const width = (info.colWidth)? "className={info.colWidth}" : "xs={this.calculateColumnSize()}";
            return (<Col style={{paddingTop:10,paddingLeft:10}} key={info.header} width>{info.header}</Col>);
    })}
</Row>
```

The reason it works when you remove the curly braces and ternary operator is because when you do a fat arrow function without curly braces for the body, it implicitly returns the body, which must be only one statement. Since you're adding a second statement in the function body (the ternary line), you need to add the body braces, and now there there are body braces, you need to actually write the `return` keyword because it's no longer implicit for your jsx line.

Comment: Good explanation TW80000. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You just forgot the **return** inside `map()`.
Inside `map()` you return for each iteration `undefined` and this will be ignored because there is nothink to render.
When you use your `fat arrow function` *with* "{}" you have to explicit return (`(x) => {return x + x}`) a variable but *without* there is a implicitly return (`(x) => x + x`).

### Solution

```
<Row className="grid-header">
    {
        this.props.columnsInfo.map(info => {
            const width = info.colWidth 
              ? "className={info.colWidth}"
              : "xs={this.calculateColumnSize()}";
            return <Col style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }} key={info.header} width>{info.header}</Col>
        })
    }
</Row>
```

Comment: @dfsq I change it to `const width`. Didn't noticed it when I answered the main error. Thanks..